# New Computer Build Won't boot with RAM in the 3rd slot

Tags: memory, motherboard, computer-building

At first when I built the machine, all 4 slots were filled with the same RAM. I know for sure the RAM is compatible with the motherboard. The computer did not boot, and it would power-cycle. I got it to boot with 1 stick of RAM at first. Then when I put the rest in, it would not boot again. I switched the memory around to make sure it's not the actual memory and it seems that it's not. It looks like it's the 3rd memory slot. Right now the system has 24 gigs of ram in it. How do I test further to determine the cause?

I am not sure if it is related to the issue, but in the image I might be seeing a bent pin (just one) on the CPU socket. I am not sure if it is actually a bent pin however, my eyesight is not good enough to discern.

[image: socket on mobo]

```
i7-5820K processor
GA-X99-UD3P motherboard
DDR4 Crucial Ballistic RAM (8GB modules)
```

Comment: That does look like a bent pin to me. I think the two things are connected. Best way to diagnose this would be with a different motherboard, which is usually pretty hard to come by, so I would suggest you take it to a local PC repair shop and have them test the CPU and memory

Comment: Thanks! I'm thinking of ordering a new MOBO since it was an amazon purchase, they are good about doing refunds. Do you know of a way to test the ram? Or the ram sockets without having the memory installed?

Comment: I dont believe there is any straightforward way to test the ram except in a motherboard. And you've already done what I would do to test the RAM sockets, which is switching the memory modules around.

Comment: What you have been doing is how you should test the memory or use use memtest86

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To further what @Ramhound said, put RAM one stick at a time into Slot 1 and run [Memtest86](http://www.memtest.org) on each stick. That will verify that the RAM is good.

Looking at those pins, they look like they are touching. Since half the pins on the CPU are for RAM (Bus, Data etc), it would make sense that it could be the thing that is causing the problem. If the Memtest86 runs good and the RAM is not the issue, then I would carefully try bending the pin back into position (I think that the easiest method is to use a 5mm mechanical pencil with no lead in it. You can use the empty barrel to bend the pin back straight.)

Comment: currently running memtest on the 3 sticks that are in the computer, then will run on the one that was left out. I'd try and bend the pin but I can't see which way it's supposed to point. It just looks like there are two pins coming from one hole. My eyesight isn't terrible, but it's challenging to see it really. If the memtest passes as OK, then I'll ship the board back with a note stating that the CPU socket was damaged

Comment: oogh it would be nasty if when they were creating the socket, and inserting the plastic over the pins it caught one and caused two pins to go to the same hole. That definitely would require you to have to send it back.... :(

Comment: Getting a replacement motherboard fixed the issue